# How to restrict users from Registering public email addresses other than company email address in RS Forms Joomla

Tags: php, forms, email, joomla

I have used RS form form for user Registration on my joomla site. There i want to make registration from only company email address for internal users. How can i do this ? Please advice. Is there any way of configure custom email domain for RS Form email validation field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) as field validation (instead of email).

1. While on the RS Form, edit the field and go to *Validations*.
2. Change the *Validation Rule* to *Regex*.
3. Set the *Regex Syntax* to `` /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@yourdomain.com$/ ``

*Note:* be sure to change "yourdomain.com" to your own domain.

Validating emails using regular expressions is not perfect. See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). The first part of the regex I suggested here is taken from [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address).

[image: RS Forms validations]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a workaround and hardcode it, you can try the following approach in code:

```
// Domain to check
$email_domain = "@mydomain.com";
// Email to check
$co_email = "joefoobar@mydomain.com"; // returns true => valid
//$co_email = "joefoobar@gmail.com"; // returns false => invalid (uncomment to test)
if(!substr_count($co_email, $email_domain) > 0){
    // Set the error
    echo "Invalid!";
} else {
    // No error, proceed with code
    echo "Valid!";
}
```